# How to center this link text vertically when the anchor contains an image

Tags: css, stylesheet

Here is the code:

```
<div><a><img src=" http://www.seeklogo.com/images/R/Random_House_Bertelsmann-logo-B80776D5CA-seeklogo.com.gif"/>Test</a>​​​​​​​​​<div>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

Here is the fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/zjfw2/

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The text is aligning based on the alignment of the image. It may seem counter-intuitive, but you need to align the image to the middle in order for the text to align properly.

```
img { vertical-align:middle; }
```